# Selecting rows that have certain number of specific type of character in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server

I need a query that will return all rows that greater than X number of commas exist in the description column. Like won't work because the commas would be spread out and the in between text would be different. I'm not certain this query exists at all.

Any insight or assistance with that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I must say it sounds like you have comma separated data in a single field.  This should be avoided if that is the case!!! Normalize!!!

Comment: Sorry, it's Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: John - I agree! This was a client's mistake that I'm trying to work around while they fix their own data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of counting the number of times a character appears in a string is to compare the string's length to the length of the string with this character removed.

So, e.g., assuming you want to find all the rows with 5 commas in col1:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  LEN(col1) - LEN(REPLACE(col1, ',', '')) = 5
```

Comment: I like this solution. Does this perform well? I've have good luck using replace, just curious if you've ever tried this on a large dataset.

Comment: When I run that, it gives me an 'Incorrect syntax error near ='. Tried surrounding the statement after where in parenthesis. Still no go. This is my query: 

SELECT top 100 *
FROM   [a1304e86-8386-4722-9c44-5373fe197247] with (nolock)
WHERE  LEN([activityAttributes.Description]) - LEN(REPLACE([activityAttributes.Description], ',', '') = 5

Comment: The code in the comment is missing a right parenthesis.

Comment: Actually, the code in my answer was missing that right parenthesis too - thanks for point it out (fixed).

Comment: @liebs19 I must confess I did not benchmark this against large datasets. Then again, I always try to figure out the functionality first and only optimize if needed.

Comment: @Mureinik I totally understand that logic and I do the same. Was just curious if you had benchmarked it or not. You never can tell how the optimizer will handle these issues.

Comment: Performance of this solution will not be fantastic over a large dataset, since SQL Server cannot use statistics or indexes to seek to rows matching the requirements.  For a large dataset, you may want to consider adding a computed column to store the number of commas in the field with an index on the computed column.

Comment: That worked! Beautiful. Thanks, Mureinik.

I ran this on a large dataset (millions of records) and, with additional search parameters, it came back under 10 seconds with nolock. I consider that pretty acceptable. As far as something like writing a report in SSRS, I'm not sure. But this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in performance, and would like to implement a slightly more complicated approach, I mocked up some data and did a relative simple test:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    TestID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Test
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , col1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    , col1_comma_count AS LEN(col1) - LEN(REPLACE(col1, ',','')) PERSISTED
);


INSERT INTO Test (col1) VALUES ('this, is, a, test');
GO 50000
INSERT INTO Test (col1) VALUES ('this, is, a, test, another, test');
GO 1500
```

The statements above create a test table with a computed column that contains the count of the number of commas in `col1`.  The table then has 50,000 rows inserted where the comma count is 3, and 1,500 rows inserted where the comma count is 5.

I then executed the following query, with `SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON;`:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.Test t
WHERE t.col1_comma_count = 5;
```

The statistics info:

[image]

As you can see, 248 logical reads are necessary to scan the entire table to obtain the count of rows where 5 commas.  The execution plan for this query looks like:

[image]

As expected, SQL Server does a clustered index scan of the entire table.

I then created an index on the persisted computed column, to show the difference:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Test_col1_comma_count ON dbo.Test (col1_comma_count);
```

and re-ran the test query.  Here are the statistics info for the run with the index:

[image]

The number of reads necessary has dropped to 6, or 41 times less reads.  On a busy system this will make a real difference.  Here is the new execution plan:

[image]

This time, we see a much more efficient seek into the index.

If we drop both the index and the computed column from the table, we see a huge increase in time spent getting the results of the query:

```
DROP INDEX IX_Test_col1_comma_count ON dbo.Test;
ALTER TABLE Test DROP COLUMN col1_comma_count;

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.Test t
WHERE LEN(col1) - LEN(REPLACE(col1, ',','')) = 5
```

`STATISTICS TIME ON` shows a value on my computer (an Intel Core-i7 3.4Ghz with 8GB ram) of  SQL Server Execution Times:   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 24 ms.

With the index and computed, persisted column in place, the SQL Server execution times are  SQL Server Execution Times:  CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.

Clearly, there is a price to pay for doing string manipulation in the `WHERE` clause.